# Malkizedek, Jerusalem and the Temple Mount

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, beis-hamikdash, yerushalayim-jerusalem, melchizedek

> וּמַלְכִּי־צֶדֶק מֶלֶךְ שָׁלֵם הוֹצִיא לֶחֶם וָיָיִן וְהוּא כֹהֵן לְאֵל עֶלְיוֹן׃
>
> And King [Melchizedek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melchizedek) of Salem brought out bread and wine; he was a priest of God Most High. ([Ber 14, 18](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.14.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi))

Many interpret Shalem as Jerusalem ([see Ebn Ezrah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.14.18?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)): "ושלם. היא ירושלם והעד ויהי בשלם סכו"

If that was Jerusalem, was it adjacent to the Temple Mount?

Because Parashat Vayerah, when Avraham wanders to find the Temple Mount, mentions no city of Shalem in the area (allegedly Malkitzedek was Shem - see Rashi and the city preceded Avraham).

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/96992/centrality-of-jerusalem-for-forefathers-and-before-temple

Comment: ויבא יעקב שלם עיר שכם sounds like it was near Nablus. But I agree with @msh that the old City of Jerusalem is clearly around the Temple mount in any normal sense of the word.